# Fraction of values in (x, y) space

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame  that looks like this, but with several hundred thousand rows:

```
df

    D   x           y
0   y   5.887672    6.284714
1   y   9.038657    10.972742
2   n   2.820448    6.954992
3   y   5.319575    15.475197
4   n   1.647302    7.941926
5   n   5.825357    13.747091
6   n   5.937630    6.435687
7   y   7.789661    11.868023
8   n   2.669362    11.300062
9   y   1.153347    17.625158
```

I want to know what proportion of values ("D") in each x:y grid space is "n".

I can do it by brute force, by stepping through x and y and calculating the percentage:

```
zonexy = {}
for x in np.arange(0,10,2.5):
    dfx = df[(df['x'] >= x) & (df['x'] < x+2.5)]
    zonexy[x] = {}
    for y in np.arange(0,24,6):
        dfy = dfx[(dfx['y'] >= y) & (dfx['y'] < y+6)]
        try:
            pctn = len(dfy[dfy['Descr']=='n'])/len(dfy) * 100.0
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            pctn = 0
        zonexy[x][y] = pctn
```

Output:

```
pd.DataFrame(zonexy)

    0.0 2.5 5.0 7.5
0   0   0   0   0
6   100 100 50  0
12  0   0   50  0
18  0   0   0   0
```

But this, and all the variations on this theme that I've tried, is very slow. It seems like there should be a much more efficient way (probably via numpy), but I'm blanking on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use the 2D histogram function of numpy:

- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html

Then,

1. Run it once on the data where the criteria is matched (here, "D" is "n")
2. Run it again on all of the data.
3. Divide the first result, element-by-element, with the second result.

Comment: Thanks; this works (once I remembered to set the range and bins based on the full dataset instead of the subset) and is much faster, a couple of seconds vs. well an hour.